# Angular - Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have my component.cs as follows:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    message: new FormControl(''),
  });

  get message(): FormControl {
    return this.profileForm.get('message') as FormControl;
  }
}
```

component.html is,

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <textarea rows="5"
  cols="100"
  maxlength="500"
  formControlName="message"
  class="form-control">
</textarea>
</form>

{{message.value.length}} of 500 characters
```

I am getting "core.js:4098 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" when the page loads and not during the inital load to enter value. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Evidently, `message.value` is null given that this is the only place you access the `.length` property. What have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: You can try `{{message.value?.length}}`

Comment: @ShamPooSham is this ternary operator in angularJS? sorry im new ...if ternary do they allow ":" for not null? because i used the same and it worked for the case i provided above . However else condition doesnt display 0

Comment: First of all, it's Angular, not AngularJS. They're actually two different things. AngularJS is used to refer to the old, javascript-based framework (version 1.x). Angular is used to refer to the newer, typescript based framework (versions 2+). 
Now, `?.` is the safe navigation operator. It's not a ternary operator, but there is a ternary `x ? y : z` operator you can use as well. You can also use `||` to do what you want, like this: `{{message.value?.length || 0}}`

Comment: You can read more about the safe navigation operator here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what the safe navigation operator is for

`{{message?.value?.length || 0}} of 500 characters`

Answer (score 1):

you can always do this:

```
<span *ngIf="message && message.value">{{message.value.length}}</span> of 500 characters
```

Answer (score 0):

the **LENGTH** property on any variable or constant in ***Typescript*** works only when the **data is not *null* or *undefined*** , so in Typescript , when dealing with length property make sure that we are setting the data as **empty** ( making the data length as zero )

Example:

```
 variableName = [];  
 constantName = {};
  
{{message?.value  ? message?.value?.length : 0 }} of 500 characters
```